# Handling crashes in perforce

Tags: perforce

I've always wondered this about Perforce transfers but haven't found a good answer:

What happens if the client crashes while syncing to a specific change list? I know that the server keeps track of which files you have. Will the file that was currently transferring during the crash be marked as having already downloaded? What about the files that haven't transfered yet?

In the past I've just done a force sync to make sure there was no corruption, but this seems really wasteful. Is there a way to do a checksum? Does perforce handle this in some graceful way I don't know about?

Any information on this would be really apreciated - Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Until the client acknowledges that is has received the file in full it will not be recorded by the server in the database as 'synced'. If a crash occurs during a sync, a sync afterwards should pick up the file. Files that haven't transferred yet will be picked up by the next sync operation.

Comment: I'm sure this is correct, but do you have a link for this out of curiosity?

Comment: We don't seem to have anything published externally on this; I'm cheating and looking at the server code. =) I'll try to write something up.

Comment: Would be interested to know more about how this works. Syncing large amounts of data over an unreliable VPN was an issue for us once. If the VPN disconnected before the sync completed, trying to sync to the same changelist after reconnecting would result in needing to resync most (if not all) of the files that seemed to have transferred previously. We ended up handling this by writing a tool that used sync preview to identify the files that needed to be synced, and syncing them one at a time.

Comment: Hot off the presses, here is an article on how sync works courtesy of one of the server devs. http://www.perforce.com/blog/140129/some-wonders-sync-command